# Algorithm for finding a formula that connects inputs and outputs

Tags: algorithm, boolean, formula

I seem to recall having learned a method for finding the formula that connects inputs and outputs from a table. For example:

```
a b c | r
1 1 0 | 0
0 1 1 | 1
1 1 1 | 1
```

where "r" is the result, and a, b and c are the inputs. The method involved equations with many unknowns and ended up with a formula that explained it all. (This is an example that is not that meaningful, since r = c, but you get the idea).

However, I can not remember the details, and not enough keywords to be able to find it on the web. The subject teaching this method also included a lot of boolean algebra.

I know this is a vague question, but what could this method for finding the formula from a table of values be?

Comment: JFYI: Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming Volume 4A* deals with this stuff, IIRC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you referring to [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)?

Comment: These could be also used, but are more for minimizing the terms (and get very complex (up to impossible) when used for more than 3 variables).

Answer (score 6):

There are disjunctive and conjuctive normalform. Depending on which you want you can build them from the (complete) logic tables by building terms for the 0 or 1 results by ors or ands and combining these terms with ands and ors (and the others match to 1 or 0). It sounds here more complex at it is. Wiki/Google will give you some examples when you look for conjunctive or disjunctive normalform.

EDIT: Here is the example from the wiki for both forms (DNF = disjunctive normal form, KNF = conjunctive normal form):
[image: Example from Wiki]

Comment: It's obvious that the KNF form could be made shorter by applying logical laws. This is where something like Karnaugh maps could do better.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean the [Cunjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form). You need the complete truth table for this, though.

Comment: Presumably he would have the complete truth table, it's just that his made-up example omitted some rows.